# Applying for a Georgia tourism visa

Tags: visas, uk, applications, georgia-country

I am applying for Georgia and UK visas. I know the UK will ask me to drop my passport for 15 days, but I don't know if Georgia will ask me to leave my passport with them. I have my visa interview on the 29th, but there is an open date for Georgia. Does Georgia ask the applicant to leave the passport with the application?

I'm applying from Malaysia, not my home country.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case, you need answers to this question. Georgia wouldn't ask you to drop off your passport. They would email you after your interview

Answer (score 1):

Do not apply for Gerorgian Visa in this specific case. Just focus on getting a UK visa. If you get it then you can go to Georgia visa free because Georgia provides  exemption  to UK visa holders.

If you have a UK visa (or from another country listed on the link below)

> **You are exempt from visa!**
>
> Holders of valid visa or residence permit of the country you have selected are exempted from visa requirements. You can enter Georgia without a visa for 90 days in any 180-day period. Please, note that you must present relevant valid visa or residence permit along with your travel document/passport at the moment of crossing Georgian border. Detailed information on visa free travel is available on the following website: www.geoconsul.gov.ge.

https://www.evisa.gov.ge/GeoVisa/en/VisaApp

Comment: Thanks for your answer. From Nigeria, but in Malaysia.

Comment: @J.Spinners see the updated answer.